# Tensorflow: 'module' object has no attribute 'scalar_summary'

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to run the following code to test my TensorBoard, however, when I ran the program, there is an error said:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'scalar_summary'
```

I want to know how can I fix this issue, thanks.

The following is the system info:

- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Tensorflow version: 0.12rc (master)
- Running environment: Jupyter Notebook

**Test program and Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The `tf.scalar_summary()` function was moved in the master branch, after the 0.12 release. You can now find it as [`tf.summary.scalar()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/summary.html#scalar).

Answer (score 30):

In a new version of TF, all [summary functions were renamed](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration).

> Summary functions have been consolidated under the tf.summary
>   namespace.

- `tf.audio_summary` should be renamed to `tf.summary.audio`
- `tf.contrib.deprecated.histogram_summary` should be renamed to `tf.summary.histogram`
- `tf.contrib.deprecated.scalar_summary` should be renamed to `tf.summary.scalar`
- `tf.histogram_summary` should be renamed to `tf.summary.histogram`
- `tf.image_summary` should be renamed to `tf.summary.image`
- `tf.merge_all_summaries` should be renamed to tf.summary.merge_all
- `tf.merge_summary` should be renamed to `tf.summary.merge`
- `tf.scalar_summary` should be renamed to `tf.summary.scalar`
- `tf.train.SummaryWriter` should be renamed to `tf.summary.FileWriter`

Comment: @Salvardor Dali, similarly are the attributes of  'tensorflow.python.ops.gen_logging_ops'  been changed? Cause i am ```log_image = gen_logging_ops._image_summary(log_image_name, tf.expand_dims(log_image_data, 0), max_images=1)``` and get attribute error as no attribute "_image_summary"