# 'module' object has no attribute 'SummaryWriter'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow version 0.12.head with Python 2.7 on a linux CentOS 7 and when I run this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(5, name="input_a")
b = tf.constant(3, name="input_b")
c = tf.mul(a, b, name="mul_c")
d = tf.add(a, b, name="add_d")
e = tf.add(c, d, name="add_e")
sess = tf.Session()
output = sess.run(e)
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('./my_graph', sess.graph)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-6-29c037e85eec> in <module>()
----> 1 writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('./my_graph', sess.graph)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SummaryWriter'
```

I have run these two commands because there is bug [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1645) on Github for the same problem:

```
>>> import six
>>> print(six.__version__)
1.10.0
>>> print(dir(six.moves.queue)) ['Empty', 'Full', 'LifoQueue', 'PriorityQueue', 'Queue', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_threading', '_time', 'deque', 'heapq']
>>> print(six.moves.queue.__file__) /usr/lib64/python2.7/Queue.pyc
```

I'm new in Python and in Tensorflow. Do you know how can I fix this error?

I have changed `SummaryWriter` with `FileWriter`:

```
writer = tf.train.FileWriter('./my_graph', sess.graph)
```

And I get the same error but with `FileWriter` function:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-daa50ea2b8f9> in <module>()
----> 1 writer = tf.train.FileWriter('./my_graph', sess.graph)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FileWriter'
```

I have also run it in a terminal and I get the same result:

```
[VansFannel@localhost ~]$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:95] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:95] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>>> a = tf.constant(5, name="input_a")
>>> b = tf.constant(3, name="input_b")
>>> c = tf.mul(a, b, name="mul_c")
>>> d = tf.add(a, b, name="add_d")
>>> e = tf.add(c, d, name="add_e")
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> output = sess.run(e)
>>> writer = tf.train.FileWriter('./my_graph', sess.graph)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'FileWriter'
>>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: 'module' object has no attribute 'scalar\_summary'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066244/tensorflow-module-object-has-no-attribute-scalar-summary)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`tf.train.SummaryWriter` is deprecated, instead use `tf.summary.FileWriter`.

↳ [Adding Summaries to Event Files](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter)

> It will be removed after 2016-11-30.
>   Instructions for updating: Please switch to `tf.summary.FileWriter`. 
>   The interface and behavior is the same; this is just a rename.

<**[`TF Official Migration Page`](https://web.archive.org/web/20180911010215/https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration)**> ✳︎ includes all current deprecated/renamed functions ✳︎

Comment: @VansFannel: It is peculiar; I'm thinking `iPython` might have something to do with it. Do you have a standard version of Python available?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with *standard version*. By the way, I'm running that code in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: I mean without iPython involved; it might help to know if that's a factor.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. I have also run that code in a terminal and I get the same error.

Comment: How it worked ? I am getting the same error when using FileWriter

Comment: @bot28: Make sure you change `train` to `summary` also; people have made that mistake.

Comment: writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/tensorflow_logs', graph=sess.graph)
I am trying this. Error : 
module' object has no attribute 'FileWriter'.

My tensorflow version is 0.11.0

Comment: @bot28: I checked and they haven't changed it again, so there must be something else causing it perhaps. I would recommend updating your tensorflow version...

Comment: to update do I need to uninstall and again install tf ?

Comment: Depends on how you installed it; if it was with `pip` then no, you can just `update` and it will take care of the rest — no uninstall or anything like that should be necessary.

Comment: Now it is depricated to use `tf.summary.FileWriter`

Answer (score 12):

In a new version of TF, all [summary functions were renamed](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration).

> Summary functions have been consolidated under the **tf.summary**
>   namespace.

```
 Deprecated                                               Replacement
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 tf.audio_summary                                         tf.summary.audio
 tf.contrib.deprecated.histogram_summary                  tf.summary.histogram
 tf.contrib.deprecated.scalar_summary                     tf.summary.scalar
 tf.histogram_summary                                     tf.summary.histogram
 tf.image_summary                                         tf.summary.image
 tf.merge_all_summaries                                   tf.summary.merge_all
 tf.merge_summary                                         tf.summary.merge
 tf.scalar_summary                                        tf.summary.scalar
 tf.train.SummaryWriter                                   tf.summary.FileWriter
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem...i am using pything 3.5.2...see solution below...hope this works for you..it did for me (it will create a log in your tmp folder):

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(5, name="input_a")
b = tf.constant(3, name="input_a")
c = tf.multiply(a,b, name="mul_c")
d = tf.add(a,b, name="add_d")
e = tf.add(c,d, name="add_e")

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(e)
output = sess.run(e)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/tensorflow_logs', graph=sess.graph)

print(sess.run(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(5, name="input_a")
b = tf.constant(3, name="input_a")
c = tf.multiply(a,b, name="mul_c")
d = tf.add(a,b, name="add_d")
e = tf.add(c,d, name="add_e")

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(e)
output = sess.run(e)

writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('/tmp/tensorflow_logs', graph=sess.graph)

print(sess.run(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

`tf.summary.create_file_writer('/pnplogs')`

`create_file_writer()` creates a summary file writer for the given log directory (which in my case is `pnplogs`)

[Read in TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/create_file_writer)