# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.training' has no attribute 'SummaryWriter'

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow

Trying to retrain the last layer of inception v3 model using new classes. I've prepared my own set of images and stored in C:\tmp. When I run the code

```
C:\tmp\image_retrain\tfClassifier\image_classification>python retrain.py --model_dir=C:\tmp\image_retrain\tfClassifier\image_classification\inception --image_dir=C:\tmp\image_retrain\tfClassifier\image_classification\styles --output_graph=C:\tmp\image_retrain\tfClassifier\image_classification\output_dir\all_ouput_stored_here.pb --how_many_training_steps 500
```

it start classfication and creating bottleneck files, but I get this error and I cannot figure what's wrong

```
    File "retrain.py", line 967, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\aamo8\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "retrain.py", line 750, in main
    train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.summaries_dir + '/train',
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.training' has no attribute 'SummaryWriter'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482913/module-object-has-no-attribute-summarywriter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SummaryWriter` has been deprecated in TensorFlow 1.0. Use `tensorflow.summary.FileWriter` instead.

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8164)