# summary.filewriter in tensorflow does not work

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

**Edit for the ones that mark this question as already being answered**

pleaseeee read my question carefully,
I am aware of the tensorflow 1 , and the changes it has,
I said I am using this right now in my code:
`train_writer = tf.train.summary.FileWriter(summaries_dir + '/train')`

but still getting error that `train_writer = tf.train.summary.FileWriter(summaries_dir + '/train')
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.training' has no attribute 'summary`

### Sooo please dont mark this question as the question that has already being answered

At first I had this piece of code:

```
train_writer = tf.train.summarywriter(summaries_dir + '/train')
```

it raises error that summarywriter....

so I changed that to this

```
train_writer = tf.train.summary.FileWriter(summaries_dir + '/train')
```

but it still raises this error`train_writer = tf.train.summary.FileWriter(summaries_dir + '/train')
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.training' has no attribute 'summary'`

may someone help me please,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43603466/1090562

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: 'module' object has no attribute 'scalar\_summary'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066244/tensorflow-module-object-has-no-attribute-scalar-summary)

Comment: @SalvadorDali pleaseeee read the question carefully, I am saying I used summary.FileWriter but still get that errooooorrr

Comment: pleeaaassee read the answer and the documentation carefully and write your question properly. First of all there is no `tf.train.summary.FileWriter` and the error tells you this exactly. Only tf.summary.FileWriter`. It works for everyone except you.

Comment: yea you are also right, so my question wasnt duplicated, it is still a unique question contains silly mistake, are u agree?

Comment: No, your question is a duplicate. Following your logic you can make infinite number of useless questions with mistakes and claim that all of them are unique.

Comment: the ultimate purpose of the site is to help all to undesrstand their bugs... even if I do agree it was silly mistake not coding issue, but what if I couldnt realize that for a week becaz it was ok with my mind, I mean in my idea the newbie like me should be supported also with their silly questions like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TF 1.x: `tf.summary.FileWriter`

Documentation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter

Note that there was a change of package names between older tensorflow versions and 1.x.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer, but as I explained I have already update that to   train_writer = tf.train.summary.FileWriter(summaries_dir + '/train')  but it still says that training does not have summary method

Comment: what is the other option to check this ,thanks for taking the time

Comment: Not tf.train, nor tf.train.summary, tf.summary. You're getting the package name wrong.

Comment: wooww you are right, silly mistake, please update your answer, then I should mark that as the answer, becaz my problem want about the changing in tf 1 but about mistakes coding, thankssss alooott